# Why can't I add SuperType to List<T> where <T extends SuperType>?

Tags: java, generics

With

```
public class SuperType {
}
```

and

```
public class TestClass<T extends SuperType > {

    public void doSomething() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        list.add(new SuperType ()); // ERROR
    }
}
```

it won't compile, giving me

> The method add(T) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (SuperType)

But why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume you have

```
public class SuperType {
}

public class SubType extends SuperType {
}
```

and use `TestClass<SubType>` your code becomes

```
public class TestClass<SubType> {

    public void doSomething() {
        List<SubType> list = new ArrayList<SubType>();
        list.add(new SuperType ());
    }
}
```

That has to error because a `new SuperType()` is not specific enough. It has to be at least a `SubType`.

Answer (score 4):

The type is only meant for sub classes of `SuperType` but not the `SuperType` itself. Instead use

```
List<SuperType> list = new ArrayList<SuperType>();
list.add(new SuperType ());
```

Answer (score 4):

You should have got something in line of-

> SuperType cannot be converted to T by method invocation conversion

Meaning using type declaration in implementation is not valid.

When you say-

```
T extends SuperType
```

You are actually saying that the parameter can be a SuperType or any subtype of your SuperType.

Should be-

```
List<SuperType> list = new ArrayList<SuperType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Type only used to express what all type it can be , in your case it can be of anytype that is a subclass of SuperType and Supertype itself.

Thanks